# How would I make it so a player can only break a door with a certain axe?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am making a minigame in Minecraft Education Edition, and want to make it so some players can open and close doors, while another has to break them with an axe. I want it so even if the player is holding anything else they can only break the door with that one axe. How would I do this? I am using 1.19.51.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in adventure mode, you could use the [Item Component](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_components#can_destroy) `can_destroy` when giving them the item. Keep in mind if they are in adventure mode they cannot break any blocks without using items with the `can_destroy` property.

```
# Give yourself a netherite axe that can only destroy oak doors.
/give @s netherite_axe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["oak_door"]}}
```